# Cannot add partition back to RAID 1

Tags: raid, mdadm, software-raid, raid1

I run an mdadm RAID 1 on my Raspberry Pi. The USB cables to the two hard disks (especially to `/dev/sda`) seem to provide somewhat loose connections or someone touches them. They are right next to the router and not in a box, so people sometimes touch stuff there. Up until now, I simply ran

```
sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sda1
```

when that happened and the RAID rebuilt.

However, now `/dev/sdb1` was removed from the RAID:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0](W)
      1952993280 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 9/15 pages [36KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

Running

```
sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1
```

results in this error message:

```
mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/sdb1 as 2: Invalid argument
```

What's the best way of getting the array back up?

Comment: Are you sure the disk is plugged in and working?  Do you see `/dev/sdb1`?  Are there any errors showing in `dmesg` output?

Comment: Can you also show the output of `lsblk` and `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` ?

Comment: @StephenHarris `lsblk` lists the device and the partition but there are errors in `dmesg`: https://pastebin.com/tFpJg0Mi Thank you for your help! I guess my hard drive is failing and I'll try to find out more. Apparently, it's not `mdadm`'s fault. Its error message is just really not useful.

Comment: @ValentinBajrami I'm not sure whether this is still relevant as we just figured out that one of the disks is failing. However, here are the outputs: https://pastebin.com/MN32uqJF https://pastebin.com/Qpg0zUzr

Comment: @UTF-8 I would check the USB connections are good and that the drive is getting good power.  I've seen external disks report I/O errors when the cable wasn't properly plugged in or when a USB-powered disk used the wrong USB cable.  For an externally powered disk, ensure the power supply is properly plugged in and turned on :-)

Comment: @StephenHarris Thanks. Unfortunately, `badblocks` already printed 4 (consecutive) numbers. :( Guess this isn't because of the USB connection, especially because I already shut the system down, removed the cables, and re-attached them.

Comment: I now posted a new question because the apparent problem changed: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485914/coping-with-bad-sectors-on-raid-disk